# Audio Video out of sync when i append videos - Android JavaCpp

Tags: java, android, append, android-mediaplayer, javacpp

I am creating videos through Android MediaRecorder..
This is  the code where i am appending the videos,
Audio is always longer then video....
Video stays stuck at the end for 3 - 5 seconds while audio keeps on playing.

```
private void doAppend(String _firstVideox, String _secondVideox,
            String _newName) {
        try {


            FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream(_firstVideox);
            FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream(_secondVideox);

            Movie[] inMovies = new Movie[] {
                    MovieCreator.build(fis1.getChannel()),
                    MovieCreator.build(fis2.getChannel()) };

            List<Track> videoTracks = new LinkedList<Track>();
            List<Track> audioTracks = new LinkedList<Track>();

            for (Movie m : inMovies) {
                for (Track t : m.getTracks()) {
                    if (t.getHandler().equals("soun")) {
                        audioTracks.add(t);
                    }
                    if (t.getHandler().equals("vide")) {
                        videoTracks.add(t);
                    }
                }
            }

            Movie result = new Movie();

            if (audioTracks.size() > 0) {
                result.addTrack(new AppendTrack(audioTracks
                        .toArray(new Track[audioTracks.size()])));
            }
            if (videoTracks.size() > 0) {

                result.addTrack(new AppendTrack(videoTracks.toArray(new Track[videoTracks.size()])));
            }

            IsoFile out = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(result);

            String filename = _newName;
            lastAppendOut = filename;

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            FileChannel fco = fos.getChannel();

            fco.position(0);
            out.getBox(fco);
            fco.close();
            fos.close();
            fis1.close();
            fis2.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

please check this out and help me, what should i do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not the problem of `JavaCpp` i suppose,
When we make video using `MediaRecorder` in android device, the audio and video are not exactly the same...
Audio is bit larger i.e. 0.1s to 0.25s
So when we append the videos using `JavaCpp` which at the end bring together the audio video stream, first appending them seperately gives a huge difference.
In my case i appended 30 to 40 videos and sometimes video audio difference went to 14 seconds, which was very distrubing...
So another approach i used was to trim every video from the end (approx 0.5s), that makes audio video stream equal.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522656/android-media-recorder-stop-exception/26624723) you can find what i did.

I hope i helped you people.